I keep getting this 'object not found' error. How do I fix it?
trying to use predict function to find ValueScore (vs in my chart) using different independent variables and a regression. encountered an error I cannot get passed.
sales <- read.csv("CarValues.csv")
sales$Size <- as.factor(sales$size)
summary(sales)
##regression\/
sales.regr <- lm( vs ~ rts + size + cpm + pr, 
                  data=sales)
##weight
carvals <- data.frame(Type="cpm", weight = .72, Type="rts", weight = 75, Type="pr", weight = 3, 
                       Type="size", weight = "Upscale Sedan")

##predict
predict(sales.regr, newdata = carvals, type="response")

here is my data

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full error.  Please clarify what language this is.

What language is this?

I'm gessing R @JohnGordon

@aidanshaw, hello and welcome, please consider adding the data as text and not as an image. Furthermore, please add a language tag
